# How do I get an error report from a "Please tell Microsoft about this" dialog?

Tags: windows-xp, error-reporting

A program I wrote crashes on startup. (Win XP).

A dialog "Please tell Microsoft about this problem." appears. I want to be told about the problem since it's my app.

Thing is, clicking through (clicking link: 'View the contents of the error report'), the "Error Report Contents" dialog doesn't let my customers copy its contents to the clipboard.

Do you know how a user can get a copy of this report to forward to me, the developer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't worry. The developers can subscribe to WinQual. Microsoft will then forward the error reports to them.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't heard of WinQual. I'll find out if the developer is a member.

Answer (score 6):

Windows Error Reporting is part of Microsoft's [Winqual](https://winqual.microsoft.com/) service.

1. Sign up at the Winqual web site.  Instead of just using a username/password to log in, you'll need to purchase an SSL certificate to identify yourself and your organization.  This costs $99 if you only need the cert for identification purposes.  If you also want to use it to sign code, it's $499.
2. Run the Microsoft Product Feedback Mapping Tool (available from the Winqual site) on a local copy of your application, and submit the results to the Winqual web site.  This registers your application with Winqual.
3. From this point forward, any errors reported via Windows Error Reporting against your submitted applications are available to you if you log in to Winqual.

Answer (score 0):

Use Alt-printscreen that grabs a copy of the active window, then paste it into word or something.